# top tube adapter for hitch mount carrier

Tags: transportation

I recently bought a Trek Navigator 1. I just installed a hitch and a Allen 2 bike rack. BUT the Trek has a verry angled top tube. so the front tire is only a couple of inches off the ground. Would a Yakima or other brand tube adapter work on the Trek? Which is stronger or rather snugger fitting?  Thanks in advance

Comment: "the front tire is only a couple of inches off the ground" - What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Yakima and Thule and probably most other rack companies have top tube adapters. They all recognize the need to accommodate the sloping top tube/y frame/children's bike market. They will all function relatively the same. Unless you have an ultra lightweight delicate carbon frame/seatpost, which I don't believe your bicycle qualifies for that, you should be fine.

Most of them are adjustable so you can make them fit snugly and securely.

Comment: I would add that when using these adapters, also use a secondary strap on the frame to the hitch rack. Bumps and rattles can knock these adapter bars around, possibly dropping a bike.

Comment: There are plenty of these adapters out there. If you search for "top tube adapter" on amazon, you'll find plenty of them.  Reading the reviews, you'll find the bigest complaints are the bar is too short and that there are metal bits that can scratch your bike.  I'm sure a mechanically inclined person could adjust the tube lengths to fit whatever bike they have, but some people are not or don't want to bother. The Swagman Bar Adapter Deluxe seemed to get good ratings and had few of these complaints made about it.  I don't have personal experience with these though.